# Using in line r code as part of a R markdown header

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I wish to use in line R code as part of a header in a r markdown file. However when i knit the  file the fonts used on the header are different. How can I ensure the fonts are the same. A simple example is below.

```
`r 1+1`  Header 
-------------------------
```

Comment: If it does not work, the only reason that I can think of is that your `knitr` version is too old. You may need to `update.packages()`. See [FAQ 1](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md).

Comment: Strange, it works just fine for me. Perhaps I'm also using an old version of knitr. *checks*

Comment: Apparently I was using 0.8. Most recent version on CRAN is 1.1.

Answer (score 9):

You can wrap content in backticks to denote r code inline, as follows:

```
## Title `r 1+1` Header
```

Comment: I needed to put a $ before the first backtick and after the last backtick.

Answer (score 2):

Without a reproducible example it is hard to be precise, but one thing you might want to consider is to use the `results="asis"` chunk option in your R code so that the results are not wrapped in a code markup block.  I am not sure how this works with inline commands, but you could use a regular R block and have it create the entire header from the R code, something like:

````
```r results="asis"
cat('# ', 1+1, " Header")
```
````