# How to produce only the title without a plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

Is it possible to generate only the title without a plot in ggplot?

```
ggplot() +labs(title = as.character(paste0(paste("title"))),
              subtitle = as.character("subtitle"))
```

I want to drop this grey Rectangle:
[image]

Comment: May I - out of pure curiosity - ask for the use case of this? Do you actually only want to "plot" text? Why do you plot it at all then? Why not rendering it differently, e.g. with markdown directly or even LaTeX?

Comment: some part of the title contains some element of codes for instance as.character(data$year)....

Comment: With implementations such as rmarkdown you can easily use this in line instead of creating plots...

Comment: could you link the proper function/post...?

Comment: for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037046/using-in-line-r-code-as-part-of-a-r-markdown-header

Comment: also check https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html and I’d have a look at the knitr package too https://yihui.org/knitr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "remove" the panel background using `theme(panel.background = element_blank())`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  labs(
    title = "title",
    subtitle = "subtitle",
    caption = "none"
  ) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

**EDIT** To reduce the white space you could reduce the height when exporting your plot, e.g. in R markdown you could use `fig.height`:

````
---
output: html_document
date: '2022-06-29'
---
```{r fig.height = 1}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  labs(
    title = "title",
    subtitle = "subtitle",
    caption = "none"
  ) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```
````

[image]

Comment: I want to avoid using so much space, that's why I need to drop this white space at all and leave only title

Comment: Okay. That wasn't clear to me. But that is not set via `ggplot2`. The size of the plot and the size of the panel depend on the size you set when you export your plot via e.g. `ggsave`. You could see that by adjusting the e.g. the size of the plot window. Hence, to achieve your desired result: Reduce the height of the exported plot, e.g. `ggsave("test.png", height = 1)`.

Comment: I need to put this plots in HTML after knit

Comment: In that case you have to set the `fig.height` via the chunk options. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `theme_void()` for this purpose using the code given below,

```
 ggplot() +labs(title = as.character(paste0(paste("title"))),
 +                subtitle = as.character("subtitle"),
 +                caption = "none") + theme_void()
```

[image: my_image]

Comment: I want to avoid using so much space, that's why I need to drop this white space at all and leave only title